# How to move the mouse pointer and click with Selenium Webdriver JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I'm new in selenium and I'm facing problems with simple tasks.

I'm trying to move the mouse to a specific area (x, y coordinates) in the page and then, click, but without success. I did read the documentation and I'm using `{bridge: true}` because of the chromewebdriver.

Here is my code:

```
var webdriver = require('selenium-webdriver'),
  By = webdriver.By,
  until = webdriver.until,
  Origin = webdriver;


var driver = new webdriver.Builder()
  .forBrowser('chrome')
  .build();


driver.get('http://www.localhost:4000/');

var actions = driver.actions({ bridge: true });

actions.mouse().move({x: 400, y: 1100, duration: 2000, origin: Origin.VIEWPORT});
```

Another question. I know there is a fourth parameter **origin** `origin: Origin.VIEWPORT`, however, I don't know if I imported it correctly.

I also don't know how to trigger the click event since I have not any selected element. I want to click in the final mouse pointer position.

Comment: I guess you should add `click()` and `perform()` into the chain

Comment: I added `.click().perform()` and got `click is not a function` error.

Comment: What language is this? Add the tag to the question!

Comment: Hi @SiKing, it's JavaScript. I added the tag. Thanks.

Comment: I have edited my answer...

Answer (score 1):

It seems that you are missing the `.perform();`.

The classic way to do this is with [Protractor](https://www.protractortest.org/#/api?view=webdriver.WebDriver.prototype.actions)

```
 // Instead of specifying an element as the target, you can specify an offset
// in pixels. This example double-clicks slightly to the right of an element.
browser.actions().
    mouseMove(element).
    mouseMove({x: 50, y: 0}).
    doubleClick().
    perform();
```

You can use `mouseMove` to the x y of the body element.

Hope this helps you!

**EDIT**

If this doesn't work for you try something like this:

```
browser.actions() .mouseMove(element, { x: 20, y: 75, }) .perform().then(() => browser.actions() .click() .perform());
```

Answer (score -1):

```
WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
JavascriptExecutor scpt = (JavascriptExecutor)driver;
scpt.executeScript("document.getElementById('[insert id]').click();");
```

Make sure you add a timer sleep in so it can let the page load and then be able to click afterwards so use `Thread.Sleep();`

Comment: The OP is asking for x,y coordinates, **not** element by id!

Comment: Hi @Xion, thanks to answer. Actually, it's not my problem. I already can click in any element. My question is how can I move the mouse to a blank area, and then, click. Thanks anyway.

Answer (score -1):

its works to me

```
//定位一個按鈕
WebElement button = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@class='page-button']"));
//new 一個移動滑鼠的物件
Actions clickAction = new Actions(driver).click(button);
//執行
clickAction.build().perform();
```

Comment: Please add your comments in English, not all users may be able to understand Chinese.